# Java: error correcting code calculator

Tags: java, calculator

How to correcting error in line

```
char oper = entrada.next(); //ERROR HERE
```

in code:

```
/*
 * Calculator
 */
package list01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex04 {

    public void metodoEx04() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        int A = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Second number: ");
        int B = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Operator +, -, *, ou /: ");
        char oper = entrada.next(); //ERROR HERE
        double res = calculadora(A, B, oper);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    static double calculadora(int n1, int n2, char operador) {
        double res;
        switch (operador) {
            case '+':
                res = soma(n1, n2);
                return res;
            case '-':
                res = subtracao(n1, n2);
                return res;
            case '*':
                res = multiplicacao(n1, n2);
                return res;
            default:
                res = divisao(n1, n2);
                return res;
        }
    }

    static double soma(int num1, int num2) {
        double res;
        res = num1 + num2;
        return res;
    }

    static double subtracao(int num1, int num2) {
        double res;
        res = num1 - num2;
        return res;
    }

    static double multiplicacao(int num1, int num2) {
        double res;
        res = num1 * num2;
        return res;
    }

    static double divisao(int num1, int num2) {
        double res;
        if (num2 != 0) {
            res = num1 / num2;
            return res;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Impossible.");
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post your complete error message for problems like this. As to the cause of your error, please check the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and see what type of object `Scanner#next()` returns. What type of variable are you assigning the returned value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next gives a string, you want a char.  You could try

```
char oper = entrada.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks #Theodore Norvell and #Doug Ramsey.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String next()
```

`next()` is returning a `String` object, if you want to store a character, you need:

```
entrada.next().charAt(0);
```

In the future when posting errors, please post the actual error.